# Local Notification every X day - Swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

Before I begin please don't burn me as I know this has been asked hundreds of times on here with no reliable answer but I believe there's a solution using background refresh. https://medisafe.com/ app seems to have solved it!

The goal :
To trigger a local notification at a specified time every x days

My solution

step 1: get timer interval from start date and odd occurrence (this case 2) days from (edited)

step 2: set interval timer on this difference with a repeat

step 3: activate background refresh ( if the app is even terminated it will load the app in the background and give me a small window to perform some tasks)

step 4. set background refresh to trigger once a day

step 5: perform get items api which will refresh all timers and notifications

step 6 sit back and smile with amazement at my solution

but this fails.

so a timer interval

```
 let newTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 172800,repeats: true)
```

but this will just reset the timer every day when the background fetch is performed and it will trigger 2 days from NOW and not from the start date.

So there must be a way of comparing dates hours and minutes (start date, x date, and current date to work out the timer interval value.

currently im using calendar components. to trigger everyday im doing the following

```
      var triggerType : DateComponents? {
    var triggerT : DateComponents?
    var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    cal.firstWeekday = 2
    if let notificationModel = self.notificationModel {
        switch notificationModel.reminderType {
        case .daily?, .weekly?:
            if let date = notificationModel.date {
                triggerT = cal.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute], from:date)
                if let weekday = notificationModel.weekday {
                    triggerT?.weekday = weekday
                }
            }
        case .alternateDays?:
            if let date = notificationModel.date {
                triggerT = cal.dateComponents([ .hour, .minute], from:date)
                // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            }
        case .monthly?:
            if let date = notificationModel.date {
                triggerT = cal.dateComponents([.day,.hour,.minute], from: date)
            }
        case .yearly?:
            triggerT = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month,.day,.hour,.minute], from: (notificationModel.date)!)
        case .oneOff?:
            triggerT = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute], from: (notificationModel.date)!)
        case .none:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let category = self.notificationModel?.category, let title = self.notificationModel?.title {
                    Toast.down("An error was discovered in \(category). Please change the occurance value for the following \(title)")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("NOTIFICATION MODEL IS CORRUPT")
    }
    return triggerT
}

func add(notification: NotificationModel){
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    if let title = notification.title,
        let body = notification.body,
        let identifier = notification.identifier {


        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.categoryIdentifier = (notification.category?.rawValue)!
        content.setValue("YES", forKeyPath: "shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground")

        var trigger : UNCalendarNotificationTrigger?

        if let triggerType = self.triggerType {

            if let occurance = notification.occurance {
                if occurance > 0 {
                }
            }
            trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerType, repeats: true)

        } else {
            return
        }

        let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let identifierString = "2\(interval)"

        var request : UNNotificationRequest!
        if notification.reminderType == .alternateDays {
            print("ADDING TIMER NOTIFICATION")
            print("REMINDER TIME = \(notification.date)")
            // 172800 = two days
            let newTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 172800,
                                                        repeats: true)
            request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifierString,
                                            content: content, trigger: newTrigger)
        } else {
            request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifierString,
                                            content: content, trigger: trigger)
        }


        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Something went wrong
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else
            {
                print("ADDING NOTIDCIATION \(content.title)")

            }
        })



        //SNOOZE OR DELETE NOTIFICATIONS
        let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Snooze",                                          title: "Snooze", options: [])
        let deleteAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "UYLDeleteAction",title: "Delete", options: [.destructive])
        //Create a category with the actions: This requires another unique identifier (you probably want to define these magic strings in an enum):
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: notification.category!.rawValue,
                                              actions: [snoozeAction,deleteAction],
                                              intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        //Register the category with the notification center. It is recommended to do this early in the app lifecycle.

        center.setNotificationCategories([category])
        //To include this action in our notifications we need to set the category in the notification content:

    } else {
        print("Failed to add notification")
    }
}
```

however, I want every other day and dont want to use the 64 notification limit.

thanks for your time

Thomas

Comment: post your code, don't (just) describe it.

Comment: i have no code. im using calendar components for everything else. i have no code solution for interval unless you want me to post empty functions of background fetch etc. this why im asking

Comment: So you only want a local notification at a specified date or?

Comment: what are calendar components, how do you use them without code?

Comment: so my code to setup notifications with calendar components works fine. i dont need to share that. its not the issue, the issue is getting a notification to be triggered every other day bearing in mind the 64 notification centre limit, i have no code for this because i dont know how to do it hence why im asking on here :). The thing is i know it can be done because https://medisafe.com/ have managed it!

Comment: first of all: there is nothing called calendar components. second: you are SO member long enough to know that you should show your effort, meaning code. third: 172800 seconds do not equal to 2 days in every case — due to DST. If we saw your code it would be much easier to help you with that stuff.

Comment: ok calendar date components if you want it to be more accurate :) I've also added code as requested

Comment: This might be a terrible work-around but theoretically, every X days can also be represented by putting a modulus on the next-highest value. For example, every 4 days will be a wednesday every N weeks, and a tuesday every P weeks... admittedly I don't have this math figured out in my head already, but I think you might get the feel for my idea. I can try to clarify more if you don't get it

Comment: yeah this could be the solution.. ill share it i fit works. thanks stephen

Comment: Do we have a solution for 3 months(quarter year) interval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets say you want to trigger notification 2, 4 and 6 days from now, here is how you can do it:

For my example I added extension to `Date`

```
extension Date {
    func adding(days: Int) -> Date? {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = days

        return NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: self)
    }
}
```

Then you could just create new notifications for dates specified, in this example 2, 4, 6 days from now

```
let date = Date()
for i in [2, 4, 6] {
    if let date = date.adding(days: i) {
        scheduleNotification(withDate: date)
    }
}

func scheduleNotification(withDate date: Date) {
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = "Title"
    notificationContent.subtitle = "Subtitle"
    notificationContent.body = "Body"

    let identifier = "Make up identifiers here"
    let dateComponents = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let notificationReques = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationReques) { error in
        if let e = error {
            print("Error \(e.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

This should schedule 3 notifications - 2, 4, 6 days from now...

Comment: this is very similar to the solution i ended up doing provided by stephen j. thanks for your help

Comment: @Ladislav Its not working, Your loop is right its giving perfect date by every two days. I am testing it by changing date from device settings. Can you please check once again? I copy and paste your same code.

Comment: @BhaveshLathigara so you change date for +2 days and wait if you get the notification?

Comment: @Ladislav yes I tested all the ways

Comment: @BhaveshLathigara At what time do you want notifications to fire...currently it will fire and the time when these methods are called

Comment: @Ladislav There is no specific time I want. But when I set it’s taking automatic to what ever the time ticking. And see your loop will only add 2 days there is no time logic. By the way I used right now is ABScheduler and it’s working fine now I will edit link here. when I got the time. Thanks for your all reply.

Answer (score 6):

So thanks for the directions on here this is the final solution i came up with. Ensure you turn on background modes in app capabilities so the current week is updated. i did mine to every day.

[image: Background Modes in Xcode]

Then the code with comments.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import UserNotifications
```

Lets create some helper clases to make it easier to work with dates

```
// HELPERS

extension Date {

public var weekday: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self)
}

public var hour: Int {
    get {
        return Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self)
    }
    set {
        let allowedRange = Calendar.current.range(of: .hour, in: .day, for: self)!
        guard allowedRange.contains(newValue) else { return }

        let currentHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self)
        let hoursToAdd = newValue - currentHour
        if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hoursToAdd, to: self) {
            self = date
        }
    }
}

public var minute: Int {
    get {
        return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self)
    }
    set {
        let allowedRange = Calendar.current.range(of: .minute, in: .hour, for: self)!
        guard allowedRange.contains(newValue) else { return }

        let currentMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self)
        let minutesToAdd = newValue - currentMinutes
        if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutesToAdd, to: self) {
            self = date
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then we create our custom notification struct

```
struct CustomNotification {

static func everyOtherDay(wtihStartDate startDate: Date) -> [Int]? {

    //
    let currentDate = Date()
    // get initial week day from start date to compare dates
    let weekDay = startDate.weekday

    // Then we need to get week of years for both dates
    let cal = Calendar.current

    guard let weekA = cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: startDate).weekOfYear else { return nil}

    guard let weekB = cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: currentDate).weekOfYear else {return nil}

    // create two arrays for week days

    let weekOne = [1,3,5,7]
    let weekTwo = [2,4,6]

    // then we create a module to check if we are in week one or week two

    let currentWeek = (weekA - weekB) % 2

    if currentWeek == 0 {
        //week 1
        return weekOne.contains(weekDay) ? weekOne : weekTwo
    } else {
        // week 2
        return weekOne.contains(weekDay) ? weekTwo : weekOne
    }
}
}
```

finally in our class where we create the notification. I personally use a notification manager. but to shwo you quickly

```
class AClass : NSObject {

func setupNotifications() {

    let startDate = Date()
    let weekDays =  CustomNotification.everyOtherDay(wtihStartDate: startDate)
    let cal = Calendar.current
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    if let weekDays = weekDays {

        for day in weekDays {

            let identifier = "Some Random ID"

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "title"
            content.body = "body"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
            content.categoryIdentifier = "SOME CATEGORY"
            content.setValue("YES", forKeyPath: "shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground")

            var components = cal.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from:startDate)
            components.weekday = day
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                            content: content, trigger: trigger)

            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    // Something went wrong
                    print("ERROR ADDING NOTIFICATION TO CENTER \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else
                {
                    print("ADDING NOTIFCIATION \(content.categoryIdentifier)")
                }
            })

        }
    }
}
}
```

Then we need to setup background fetch in our app and app delegate

```
        // OVER IN APP DELEGATE

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // setup background refresh ensuring you turn it on in app capabilities
    // trigger back ground refrsh once a day
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(86400)

    return true

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
     // FETCH DATA and REFRESH NOTIFICATIONS
    // We need to do this to ensure the current week value is updated to either 1 or 0
    // You will need to delete all notifications with same same category first else your going to be getting both weeks notifications
    let  aClass = AClass()
    aClass.setupNotifications()
}
```

Hope this helps somebody :D Thomas

Comment: please note that a day  might have 24, 23 or 25 hours, due to DST. You need to make sure that switching to and from summer time does not mess up things.

Comment: this is a good catch if you are on weekday 7 and 11 - 1am. thanks for you input viking

Comment: as far as I understand it, the trigger time will be off 1 hour for half a year. That might be no problem in your app. Dear @futurreader: be aware of possible issues if you encounter an interval of 86400 seconds.

Comment: you can also determine the right interval like `let d =  Date(); 
let timeinterval = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: d)!.timeIntervalSince(d)`

Comment: this will give you the time interval to the same time next date, no matter if it is 23, 24 or 25 hours.

Comment: Note that 'setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval' was deprecated in iOS 13.0.